# Exposed dropdown menu's AutoCompleteTextView option disappear after press back arrow button from DetailFragment back to ThumbnailFragment

Tags: android, menu, autocompletetextview

Exposed dropdown menu's AutoCompleteTextView option disappear after chose one option and enter into detail page then press back arrow button from DetailFragment back to ThumbnailFragment.

Why?

[image: ThumbnailFragment]

[image: DetailFragment]

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead of current events? also provide your code.

Comment: I want to show all options.

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for problems/issues about the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0):

use this in xml.

android:inputType="none"

Comment: Not this problem. This is like Spinner View. Originally can't let people type. Only can be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spinner instead of Exposed dropdown menu then solve this problem.